# Display a raw string from a "regex-like" string

Tags: python, regex, string, printing

I'm a beginner in programming and I just have a small issue:

I have a string stored as follow:

```
['State start_ping_3\n{\n   \t// send ping\n\n\tAssign addr Ping_RemoteAddr3;\n\tAssign pingParams Ping_Parameters3;\n\n\tBuild Out GUE_startCommand;\n\tAssign Out.ref\t11;\n\t//Assign Out.command\t"/ercom/bundles/startPing.sh -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%";\n\tCase(PDNType = 2) // IPv6\n\t{\n\t\tAssign Out.command\t"$BUNDLE_BIN_PATH/ping6 -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%";\n\t}\n\tDefaultCase(PDNType)\n\t{\n\t\tAssign Out.command\t"$BUNDLE_BIN_PATH/ping -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%"; // -w 8: 8sec timeout then exit ping\n\t}\n\tSend Out To\tUE;\n\tAdd ping_traffic3 1;\n\t\n\tIf (_ActivateEvents>=1) {Log "Start Ping 3";}\n\tReturn;\n}']
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to display it (with Tk or with a print) normally.
Meaning:

```
State start_ping_3
{
    // send ping

    Assign addr Ping_RemoteAddr3;
    Assign pingParams Ping_Parameters3;

    Build Out GUE_startCommand;
    Assign Out.ref  11;
    //Assign Out.command    "/ercom/bundles/startPing.sh -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%";
    Case(PDNType = 2) // IPv6
    {
        Assign Out.command  "$BUNDLE_BIN_PATH/ping6 -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%";
    }
    DefaultCase(PDNType)
    {
        Assign Out.command  "$BUNDLE_BIN_PATH/ping -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%"; // -w 8: 8sec timeout then exit ping
    }
    Send Out To UE;
    Add ping_traffic3 1;

    If (_ActivateEvents>=1) {Log "Start Ping 3";}
    Return;
}
```

Isn't there a way to somehow convert this string?

I'm sure it's a very basic question but I searched everywhere for a solution without any success.

Thanks a lot for you help

BR.

Comment: doesn't look like python to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your list has only 1 element, so printing it should work:

```
list = ['State start_ping_3\n{\n   \t// send ping\n\n\tAssign addr Ping_RemoteAddr3;\n\tAssign pingParams Ping_Parameters3;\n\n\tBuild Out GUE_startCommand;\n\tAssign Out.ref\t11;\n\t//Assign Out.command\t"/ercom/bundles/startPing.sh -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%";\n\tCase(PDNType = 2) // IPv6\n\t{\n\t\tAssign Out.command\t"$BUNDLE_BIN_PATH/ping6 -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%";\n\t}\n\tDefaultCase(PDNType)\n\t{\n\t\tAssign Out.command\t"$BUNDLE_BIN_PATH/ping -I %pdn_add% %pingParams% %addr%"; // -w 8: 8sec timeout then exit ping\n\t}\n\tSend Out To\tUE;\n\tAdd ping_traffic3 1;\n\t\n\tIf (_ActivateEvents>=1) {Log "Start Ping 3";}\n\tReturn;\n}']
print list[0]
```

The string that is printed will be properly formatted (with tabs, newlines).

Comment: Actually I converted the list into a string and the problem was solved:
<pre>
str="".join(list[0])
print str
<code>

Answer (score 0):

If you just print the string, it should show it to you without all the "\" elements:

```
a = ['\tabc\t']
print a[0]
>>>   abc
```

If you want to keep all the stuff inside:

```
a = ['\n\tabc\t\n']
print repr(a[0])
>>>'\n\tabc\t\n'
```